# Is Emerald Theme Manager available for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, emerald

I tried to search Emerald Theme Manager in Ubuntu Software Center but it's not available?

Comment: Thanks Johnny, I installed Emerald Theme Manager, but i can not apply new theme for my Ubuntu. Does Unity (Ubuntu 14.04) support Emerald Theme Manager?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is. Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:noobslab/themes

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install emerald
```

Done.

How to activate and use Emerald look [here](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/02/emerald-decorator-and-themes-available.html)

Comment: **WARNING!** As the article suggested, Window decoration plugin is not available under unity in 14.04. It will create conflict with Unity.